# How do I browse a local network if my IP is an IPv6

Tags: apache, testing, mobile, localhost

Previously I could browse my localhost machine on a mobile device connected over wifi using my ip which was IPv4.

In developing a webapp or website this is very handy. I don't have to deploy changes to a live website/host.
previously this worked like this http://11.22.33.44/ entering this on the mobile then loaded the development workspace in the device.
Of course the ip was the one given by my ISP now the IP is a IPv6 one and this technique no longer works. I have tried various things like square brackets around the number http://[1111:2222:3333:4444]/this doesn't seem to work ?